# Call to a member function get_courses() on null CI4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

Im having an issue using CI4

I kept on getting error "Call to a member function get_courses() on null" even though this function exist on my model. Here's how I code it.

courseModel.php

```
public function get_courses() //get courses under the teacher
{
    $builder = $this->db->table('tbl_course_access');

    $builder->select('*');
    // $builder->where('user_id', $userid);
    // $builder->where('school_id', $schoolid);
    //$builder->groupBy('course_id');
    $query = $builder->get();

    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```

and on my controller I call it like this

Dashboard.php

```
$temp = $this->courseModel->get_courses();
var_dump($temp);
exit;
```

note that I called the model properly base on the CI manual

```
$this->courseModel = model('App\Models\CoursetModel', false);
```

What did I do wrong or any configuration I need to do on CI4?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had typos on my codes that makes the error! Must be a headache doing all the work!